# can't able to access URL using webview in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I am tring to access a url from a server into my webview. But it's returning following error;

```
[ERROR] : Error loading: (null), Error: Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=101 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (WebKitErrorDomain error 101.)"
```

When i hardCoded that same URL(from webservice) into webview, I am able to get corresponding webpages.[url : "https:\...........%20n%20..."]

```
webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top : 0,
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    html : service.sampleURL,
});
```

How can i consume URL directly from server instead of hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebKitErrorDomain error 101` means `WebKitErrorCannotShowURL`. Check how exactly url retrieved from the server looks like and is it encoded, if so use `decodeURIComponent()`.

Also creation of WebView should looks like:

```
webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    top : 0,
    width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
    url : service.sampleURL,
});
```

If it doesn't work, provide more code so we could see more exactly where is a problem.

Comment: Hi @daniula, my URL link isn't encoded & doesn't contain any Hebrew formats. I added decodeURIComponent(),still same error. When i hardcode link in "url" parameter,it's working fine.

Comment: When you are pulling url from your server do you use `url` property or `html` property while creating WebView object?